# Generate a Random key based on Input Number

Tags: algorithm, math, random, hash

I have a list of integers (emplyoee ID's)
They are 8 digits long (although almost all start 00, but they are effectively 8 digits long)

For each employee I need to generate a key that is:

```
- 5 chars including [A-Z][a-z][0-9]
- Must include 1 of [A-Z]
- Must include 1 of [0-9]
- Generated key must be unique
- If I know an employees ID I should not be able to determine their key
```

I need to produce an algorithm that will generate the keys but I want to avoid having to record keys against employees if possible. The more I think about it the more problems I encounter.

If I can avoid it I don't want to generate all the keys and store them somewhere - I would rather they are calculated on the fly

I am allowed to hide a secret in my system which I could use to make sure the keys are non deterministic unless you know the secret.

I thought of using standard hash algroythms (with salt) but the limits of the target space and limits of including 1 A-Z and 1 0-9 seem to prevent this.

One way I think I might use to solve the problem:

```
1. Build a deteremnistic function that maps integers starting from 1 [1, 2, 3, ...] to every possible result value
2. Map integers [1, 2, ...] to random other integers in the desired range [324, 43565, ...] in a way that preserves uniqueness (based on a secret salt which if changed would result in a different order).
```

This would guarantee uniqueness but step 1 is tricky. The result set is discontinuous, some values may be missing a capital letter and others will miss a number.

I could get round this by starting every code with A1 which technically would work but reduced the result space from a 5 chars to 3 chars.

Can anyone suggest something simple that will work and avoid me having to keep a record of all generated results for unique checking?

Comment: For the password encoding part: take the first character from [A-Z], the second from [0-9] and the remaining three characters from the whole set. That gives you 26*10*62*62*62 (= 61,965,280) possibilities. That doesn't completely cover the 8-digits, but comes close - so you probably don't need to vary the [A-Z] and [0-9] positions. With a bit of math, you can convert both ways between password and [0-61,965,279] number.

Comment: If you really need to cover the whole 8-digit range, map numbers below 50,000,000 to [A-Z][0-9][?][?][?] and those above to [0-9][A-Z][?][?][?]. The string patterns don't overlap. Decision for string-generation and for parsing are simple: number below 50,000,000 vs. first character is letter.

Comment: I am glad I posted here Ralf, that answer to number 1 is the way to go. Any ideas for the deterministic, unique and secret based mapping function from Employee ID to the key?

Comment: Sorry, not really an idea for the second part. I'm tempted to say "encryption", but can you encrypt a (roughly) 27.6 bit input to a 27.6 bit output and later decrypt the result? I don't know. Maybe if you could guarantee numbers within 24 bits (16 mio.), meaning a 3-byte text. I'm not a crypto expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Ralf the easiest way to achieve the required amount of variation of keys is to probably change the position of the capital letter and number, giving you `2 * 26 * 10 * 62 * 62 * 62` or `>120000000` possible combinations.

To make the key not directly derivable from an employee ID I suggest a simple XOR with another secret 8 digit number. Then use a simple modulus followed by division for each character.

```
char = x % 62
x = (x - (x % 62)) / 62
```

For instance in javascript:

```
function ID2Key(id, secret) {
    var table = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    var key = new Array(5); // Initialize the key
    // Changed XOR to a ROT10
    // var scrambled = id ^ secret; // "Encrypt" the employee ID with a secret
    var scrambled = 0;
    while (id) {
        var rotated = ((id % 10) + (secret % 10)) % 10;
        scrambled = (scrambled * 10) + rotated;
        id = Math.floor(id / 10);
        secret = Math.floor(secret / 10)
    }

    var capital_index = scrambled % 2; // Determine if the Capital letter should be first
    scrambled = (scrambled - capital_index) / 2;
    var capital = table[36 + (scrambled % 26)]; // Find the capital letter
    key[capital_index] = capital;
    scrambled = (scrambled - (scrambled % 26)) / 26;

    var num = scrambled % 10; // Find the number
    key[1-capital_index] = table[num]; // If the capital letter is first place the number second and visa versa
    scrambled = (scrambled - (scrambled % 10)) / 10;

    // Find the remaining 3 characters
    key[2] = table[scrambled % 62];
    scrambled = (scrambled - (scrambled % 62)) / 62;

    key[3] = table[scrambled % 62];
    scrambled = (scrambled - (scrambled % 62)) / 62;

    key[4] = table[scrambled % 62];
    return key.join("");
}
```

Live Demo [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/tayejagaji/edit?html,js,output)

**Edit Addressing XOR Failures** - To address the failure cases brought up in the comments I changed the method of scrambling the ID to a Rotation based on the secret which can now also be an 8 digit number.

**Edit Clarifying vulnerabilities** - Since I now understand the requirements a little better, mainly employee's will know their ID and key, I should clarify some cryptographic concepts. Given the fairly small input range, and restrictive output there is no possible way to make the key cryptographically secure. Even using a well established encryption algorithm like a 128 bit AES the resulting strength won't be any better than at most `100000000` brute-force attempts to crack, which is insignificant to compute. With that in mind, the only way to have some semblance of security would be that the secret **and** the algorithm remain secret. In that case a person attempting the derive the secret from the ID and key couldn't know they were correct unless they had access to multiple ID-key pairs.

Comment: XOR of two "random" 8-digit numbers can result in a 9-digit one (up to 134,217,727), which is slightly more than the 2 * 61,965,280 range our encoding scheme can cover. So we could add a third encoding range [A-Z][A-Z][0-9][?][?], giving another 26*26*10*62*62 possibilities that don't overlap with the first two ranges.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff Good point, unfortunately making that change would reduce the cryptographic "strength" of the resulting keys from `308873088` to `179345664` so it might be better to be more restrictive on the range of valid secrets because this is in theory a [One-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) so the secret is unbreakable even if it is very short. I'll have to think about that a bit more and I'll make that edit if I don't find a better way

Comment: Also every employee will know their id and their key so if I understand what you said can calculate the secret

Comment: I've edited the question to address those concerns. It's important to note the range of data being protected here is small enough and restrictive enough that to my knowledge it isn't even theoretically possible to stop a genuine effort to break the "encryption" if the attacker knows the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had a slight feeling in the back of my mind that the restriction of 5 chars and the various limits our payment provider are providing were weak but you have been able to explain why quite clearly. I think we will end up just assigning random keys to people and checking uniqueness manually by storing every key I have assigned and doing database lookups to check.